# Filtering using Gabor filter

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filter, convolution

I have implemented a Gabor filter but don't know how to convolve it with the input image so as to get the desired result.My input image is of size 240*320 and i am dividing it into a block of 17*17..so there are 14*18 =255  blocks in total..I am also not sure what should be the size of Gabor filter and should i need to convolve each filter (14*18 = 252 filters)to each block or whole image..

here is my code..

```
    % compute Gabor filter  
        sigma_x = 4;
        sigma_y = 4;
        w = 17;   % size of block
        wg = 5;  % size of filter
        Gabor = zeros(m1,n1);  

        for i = 9:w:240-w           
            for j3 = 9:w:320-w

                pim = im(i-ww:i+ww,j-ww:j+ww);  % block of input image
                f = F(i,j);                     %each block contains single value 
                                                of freuency and theta
                O = theta(i,j);
                [x,y] = meshgrid(-floor(wg/2):floor(wg/2));


                x_phi = x.*cos(O) + y.*sin(O);
                y_phi = -x.*sin(O) + y.*cos(O);

                x_val = ((x_phi).^2)./(sigma_x.^2);
                y_val = ((y_phi).^2)./(sigma_y.^2);

                h = exp(-0.5*(x_val+y_val)).*cos((2*pi*f).*(x_phi));
                Gabor(i-ww:i+ww,j-ww:j+ww) = conv2(pim,h,'same');

                end;              
            end;
```

[image: my output]

output image is of fingerprint and should not consisit of white dots on black fingerprint line.

Comment: I'm not expert in matlab but you need to convolve your image and gabor kernel in frequency domain by using FFT and put the image back using Inverse FFT. For the kernels I think the most important parameters are scale and orientation, for example you decide scale = 4 and orientation = 6, you will need to create 24 kernels. The size of gabor kernel doesn't matter as long as it big enough for scale parameter

Comment: thanks@ azer89 and luis..i think i have implemented the gabor equation correctly ..is there any method to remove pore from the fingerprint ridge

Comment: As of R2015b release of the Image Processing Toolbox, you can create a Gabor filter bank using the `gabor` function in the image processing toolbox, and you can apply it to an image using `imgaborfilt`.